# Overlap two (text) data.frames by position [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this two tables:

```
> u1 <- structure(list(s1 = c("", "", "MO;SP", ""), s2 = c("", "", "", 
""), s3 = c("", "MO;SP", "", "")), row.names = c("g1", "g2", 
"g3", "g4"), class = "data.frame")

> u2 <- structure(list(s1 = c("", "", "snv", ""), s2 = c("", "", "", 
""), s3 = c("", "snv", "", "")), row.names = c("g1", "g2", "g3", 
"g4"), class = "data.frame")

> u1; u2
      s1 s2    s3
g1               
g2          MO;SP
g3 MO;SP         
g4               
    s1 s2  s3
g1           
g2        snv
g3 snv       
g4
```

and I'm looking for a final result like this one:

```
    s1  s2  s3
g1  
g2          MO;SP;snv
g3  MO;SP;snv   
g4
```

I can guess `mapply` could be an option but I cannot find the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an option is to use `paste` in `Map` and use `sub` to remove `;`.

```
list2DF(Map(\(x, y) sub("^;$", "", paste(x, y, sep=";")), u1, u2))
#         s1 s2        s3
#1                       
#2              MO;SP;snv
#3 MO;SP;snv             
#4
```